# Hibernate не создает таблицу

Tags: java, hibernate

В чем может быть проблема? Все таблицы и связи создались кроме одной(`Order`). 
Возможно кто-то сможет понять в чем ошибка.

```
@Table(name="order")
@Entity
public class Order implements Serializable {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;

@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="user_id", nullable=false)
private Account user;

@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="order")
private List<Dish> dishes;

@Column(name="order_date")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Calendar orderDate;

@Column(name="order_status", nullable=false)
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private OrderStatus status;

@Column(name="amount")
private Double amount;

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public Double getAmount() {
    return amount;
}

public void setAmount(Double amount) {
    this.amount = amount;
}

public Account getUser() {
    return user;
}

public void setUser(Account user) {
    this.user = user;
}

public List<Dish> getDishes() {
    return dishes;
}

public void setDishes(List<Dish> dishes) {
    this.dishes = dishes;
}

public Calendar getOrderDate() {
    return orderDate;
}

public void setOrderDate(Calendar orderDate) {
    this.orderDate = orderDate;
}

public OrderStatus getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(OrderStatus status) {
    this.status = status;
}

}



@Table(name="account")
@Entity
public class Account extends DomainBase implements Serializable {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@Column(name = "id")
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;

@Column(name = "username", length = 50, unique = true)
private String username;

@Column(name = "password", length = 100)
private String password;

@Column(name = "firstname", length = 50)
private String firstname;

@Column(name = "lastname", length = 50)
private String lastname;

@Column(name = "email", length = 50)
private String email;

@Column(name = "enabled")
private Boolean enabled;

@Column(name = "lastpasswordresetdate")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date lastPasswordResetDate;

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(
        name = "user_authority",
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "authority_id", referencedColumnName = "id")})
private List<Authority> authorities;

@Column(name = "authority")
private String authority;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="user", fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
private List<Order> order;

public String getAuthority() {
    return authority;
}
public void setAuthority(String authority) {
    this.authority = authority;
}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public List<Order> getOrder() {
    return order;
}
public void setOrder(List<Order> order) {
    this.order = order;
}
public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public String getFirstname() {
    return firstname;
}

public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
    this.firstname = firstname;
}

public String getLastname() {
    return lastname;
}

public void setLastname(String lastname) {
    this.lastname = lastname;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public Boolean getEnabled() {
    return enabled;
}

public void setEnabled(Boolean enabled) {
    this.enabled = enabled;
}

public Date getLastPasswordResetDate() {
    return lastPasswordResetDate;
}

public void setLastPasswordResetDate(Date lastPasswordResetDate) {
    this.lastPasswordResetDate = lastPasswordResetDate;
}

public List<Authority> getAuthorities() {
    return authorities;
}

public void setAuthorities(List<Authority> authorities) {
    this.authorities = authorities;
}

}

@Table(name="dish")
@Entity
public class Dish implements Serializable{

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;

@Column(nullable=false)
private String name;

@Column
private Double weight;

@Column
private Double price;

@Column
private String description;

@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="order_id", nullable=false)
private Order order;

@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="category_id", nullable=false)
private Category category;

@ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name="dish_ingredients",
           joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="dish_id")},
           inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="ingredient_id")})
private List<Ingredient> ingredients;

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public Double getPrice() {
    return price;
}

public void setPrice(Double price) {
    this.price = price;
}

public Order getOrder() {
    return order;
}

public void setOrder(Order order) {
    this.order = order;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public Double getWeight() {
    return weight;
}

public void setWeight(Double weight) {
    this.weight = weight;
}

public Category getCategory() {
    return category;
}

public void setCategory(Category category) {
    this.category = category;
}

public List<Ingredient> getIngredients() {
    return ingredients;
}

public void setIngredients(List<Ingredient> ingredients) {
    this.ingredients = ingredients;
}

}
```

Comment: Очень много лишней инфы - сеттеры и геттеры в вопросе явно не нужны. А нужной инфы нет - просто не создаёт, выпадает ошибка или ещё что? И где код собственно создания? Как оно должно по дефолту создаваться? Получалось ли раньше? Откуда черпали инфу о создании? Мало инфы - нема ответа.

Comment: Ошибки никакой не отдает. 
Гибернейт автоматически создает таблице в базе после деплоя, по этому кода создания нету, только описанные ентити. 
Таблицы аккаунт и диш создались, а вот ордер нет.

Comment: Ну... Попробуйте локализовать проблему, удаляя колонки в таблице проблемной - может в них что не так...

Comment: Во-первых, покажите логи hibernate. Во-вторых, `order` - зарезервированное слово в sql, и создавать таблицу с таким именем не очень разумно.

Comment: @Roman проблема была именно в этом. уже решено

Comment: В таком случае опубликуйте и примите [свой](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема была в том, что как уже упомянули выше `Order` это зарезервированное слово в SQL. Изменив названия таблицы, она создалась.